# Инициализация переменных в c++

Tags: c++, переменные

Как в c++ создать переменную с названием, введённым  с клавиатуры или сгенерированным автоматически? То есть допустим есть значение 1, а спрашивается в консоли как назвать переменную с этим значением.

Comment: эм... зачем? ..

Comment: Пока нет рефлексии никак

Comment: Названия переменных существуют только на этапе разработки (написания кода). После компиляции их нет. | Можно использовать словарь - `std::map` - в нём вы можете сопоставить значение ключу (названию).

Comment: Просто интересно... Допустим, вы это сделали. А дальше что?

Comment: Лучше взять std::unordered_map

Answer (score 1):

Имена переменных хранятся в памяти компьютера. Пользователь никак не может с ним воздействовать. Это впринципе не нужно.

Зачем вам надо, чтобы переменная называлась, как хочет пользователь? Вы можете спросить у пользователя значение переменной.

Не представляю, зачем это может быть полезным, но вы можете спросить название переменной и записать его в отдельную string переменную, однако смысла в этом нет, так как пользователь никак не может увидеть названия переменных

Comment: *"Имена переменных хранятся в памяти компьютера"* Только на время компиляции.

Comment: *`"пользователь никак не может увидеть названия переменных"`* -- debugger-ом никогда не пользовались?

Comment: Представьте, что вы пользуетесь какой-либо программой или играете в какую-либо игру. Незнание имени переменной, в которую в программе записан ваш ник или количество ваших жизней и номер уровня является для вас важной проблемой?    Если вам конечно это так важно, то я перефразирую: 'Пользователю не нужно имя переменной, вследствие чего он даже не будет пытаться ее получить'